# Should/can I use `assoc` in this function to redefine a function argument?

Tags: algorithm, clojure

I am implementing the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm in Clojure for a class project and having some issues. The issue lies in the final lines of the algorithm

```
BronKerbosch1(R, P, X):
 if P and X are both empty:
       report R as a maximal clique
   for each vertex v in P:
       BronKerbosch1(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v))
       P := P \ {v} ;This line
       X := X ⋃ {v} ;This line
```

I know in Clojure there is no sense of "set x = something". But do know there is the `assoc` function which I think is similar. I would like to know if `assoc` would be appropriate to complete my implementation.

In my implementation graphs are represented as so

```
[#{1 3 2} #{0 3 2} #{0 1 3} #{0 1 2}]
```

Where the 0th node is represented as the first set in the vector, and the values in the set represent edges to other nodes. So that above represents a graph with 4 nodes that is complete (all nodes are connected to all other nodes).

So far my algorithm implementation is

```
(defn neighV [graph, v]
  (let [ret-list (for [i (range (count graph)) :when (contains? (graph i) v)] i)]
    ret-list))

(defn Bron-Kerbosch [r, p, x, graph, cliques]
  (cond (and (empty? p) (empty? x)) (conj cliques r)
        :else
        (for [i (range (count p))]
          (conj cliques (Bron-Kerbosch (conj r i) (disj p (neighV graph i) (disj x (neighV graph i)) graph cliques)))
          )))
```

So right now I am stuck altering `p` and `x` as per the algorithm. I think that I can use `assoc` to do this but I think it only applies to maps. Would it be possible to use, could someone recommend another function?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. `assoc` isn't really `map a = something`, it returns a new map with the altered or added K/V pair included. So if there did exist `assoc` for sets, doing `(assoc someSet 2)` wouldn't modify someSet, you would just have a new set.

Comment: Ahh, I see.. I guess I was thinking about it incorrectly. I guess what I need then is a way to redefine a variable in place.

Comment: KDecker: it's a provable foundation of functional programming that you never need to update anything in place. The `for` needs to be changed to a `reduce` or `loop` so that each step sees an updated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assoc` does not alter its argument. Like all of the other basic collection operations in Clojure it returns a new immutable collection.

In order to do updates "in place", you will need to stop using the basic Clojure datatypes, and use the native Java types like `java.util.HashSet`.

The other (and preferred) option is to refactor your algorithm so that all updates are passed to the next iteration or recursion of the code.

Here is an initial attempt to adjust your code to this style, with the caveat that an inner modification may need to be pulled up from the recursive call:

```
(defn Bron-Kerbosch
  [r p x graph cliques]
  (if (every? empty? [p x])
    (conj cliques r)
    (reduce (fn [[cliques p x] v]
              (let [neigh (neighV graph v)]
                [(conj cliques
                       ;; do we need to propagate updates to p and x
                       ;; from this call back up to this scope?
                       (Bron-Kerbosch (conj r v)
                                      (disj p neigh)
                                      (disj x neigh)
                                      graph
                                      cliques))
                 ;; here we pass on the new values for p and x
                 (disj p v)
                 (conj x v)]))
            [cliques p x]
            (range (count p)))))
```

Comment: If you would expect the recursive call to `Bron-Kerbosch` to change the parent's value of `p` and `x`, Bron-Kerbosch will need a helper function so that it can either return the `cliques` along with new values of `p` and `x` to the caller, or just return the `cliques` for the top level case.

Answer (score 0):

I think given your comment, you'd be better served using `loop` and `recur`. It's really not much different than what you have now, but it would eliminate the recursive function call.